# ASP.Net Website Routing

Tags: asp.net, url-routing

I have an ASP.NET website in framework 4.0
This website contains a subvirtual directory say directory1.

I want to add routing like when I type in browser
`www.mydomain.com/funds` it will get contents from `www.mydomain.com/directory1`

Example 2

```
**www.mydomain.com/funds/page1**
```

it will get contents from

```
**www.mydomain.com/directory1/page1**
```

URL in browser should remain `**www.mydomain.com/funds/page1**`

I have added reference of System.Web.Routing for this purpose. Initially tried with `routes.MapPageRoute` but there are no physical pages as directory1 is an wordpress website.

Any suggestions will be appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may try [URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) if you're using IIS for hosting website.

Comment: As far as I know url rewrite will redirect user to url based on matching pattern .. whereas I want to keep url unchanged .. like in MVC when you type www.mysite.com/product/tv   .. it will get data from say any controller DemoController and Action "Test" as we can routes for that...

Comment: You were talking about `redirect` using URL Rewrite, 
@Mania. The very outstanding feature of that IIS module is `rewrite` behavior.